# Mongoid 4 .or not working in complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid4

I know Mongoid 4 is still in beta and maybe I've found a bug, but I'm having a hard time understanding why the first query works and the second one returns nothing:

```
Product.or({sender_uid: params[:user_id]}, {receiver_uid: params[:user_id]})
Product.where({sender_uid: params[:user_id]}).or({receiver_uid: params[:user_id]})
```

It sort of making it hard to compose any complex queries, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following example:

```
Product 1: sender_uid = 1, receiver_uid = 2
Product 2: sender_uid = 2, receiver_uid = 1
Product 3: sender_uid = 1, receiver_uid = 2

params[:user_id] = 1
```

In the first query what you are getting is **ALL** the products where the `sender_uid` **OR** the `receiver_uid` is equal to `1`. That is Product 1, 2 and 3.

In the second query you are querying all products where the `sender_uid` is `1`. That is Product 1 and Product 3 and then (on that criteria), the products with `receiver_id` = 1. Neither the Product 1, not the Product 2 have a receiver with uid 1. So, that's why you're getting nothing. What you are doing  in the second query is something like:

```
Product.where(sender_uid: params[:user_id]).where(receiver_uid: params[:user_id])
```

**UPDATE:**

Answering to a comment:

```
Product.or({ product_id: 1 }, { product_id: 2, sender_uid: 2 })
```

As you can see, the `or` method receive to Hashes of conditions. Each one is like a `where` query.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I was misunderstanding exactly what the .or and .and methods do (i.e. adding a completely new criteria instead of modifying the existing criteria).  If that's the case, how would one implement a more complex query like the following: product_id = 1 OR (product_id = 2 AND sender_uid = 2)?